# How to check if EOF comes first in getline() function in C?

Tags: c, char, eof, getline, strlen

I have this code:

```
int main(void){

  printf("Type something:\n");
  while(1){
    char * array = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    
    getline(&array, &size, stdin);

    if( (strlen(array) == 0) && feof(stdin) ){
      free(array);
      return 0;
    };
    
    /* do something else */
    free(array);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to end my program, when the first thing comes from input is EOF, but valgrind shows `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. I know the problem must be `strlen(array)`, but do not know, how to do it a different way. I can do:

```
if(feof(stdin)){
  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

but, if someone type a string and then end it with EOF, my program would stop too and I don't want that (because I need to do something else with that string). Any suggestion please? I am a beginner at C language.

Comment: Getline() returns a value (a ssize_t). Use it.

Comment: And if it gets EOF, it won't update `array`. It's still `NULL` and you can't call `strlen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wildplasser suggested, use the following code.

```
int main(void){

  printf("Type something:\n");
  while(1){
    char * array = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    
    ssize_t read = getline(&array, &size, stdin);

    if((read < 0 || (strlen(array) == 0)) && feof(stdin) ){
      free(array);
      return 0;
    };
    
    /* do something else */
    free(array);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. My bad. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick answer guys. Appreciate it.